# Parse columns from XLSX to CSV/JSON

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

Is there a solution to read multiple columns out of an XLSX and parse them into separate CSV/JSON files?

Comment: i tried to parse the whole xlsx to an .json (with xlrd and xlwt) and split it from there into multiple .json ...was wondering if there are better solutions.

Comment: post your code then, so we know what has been going wrong.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't precise enough.
my code worked but the question was more like 'what would be a good practise?'
my fault.

Comment: The same still applies - we don't know how to improve what you've done if you aren't showing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', 'Sheet2', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

For more details check this link - http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#ewx-pandas

Comment: This exports a single sheet, with minimal flexibility.